# MongoDB compound index, aggregation performance

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-indexes

I've gone through many articles about indexes in MongoDB but still have no clear understanding of indexing strategy for my particular case.

I have the following collection with more than 10 million items:

```
{
    active: BOOLEAN,
    afp: ARRAY_of_integers
}
```

Previously I was using aggregation with this pipeline:

```
pipeline = [
    {'$match': {'active': True}},
    {'$project': {
        'sub': {'$setIsSubset': [afp, '$afp']}
    }},
    {'$match': {'sub': True}}
]
```

Queries were pretty slow, so I started experimenting without aggregation:

```
db.collection.find({'active': True, 'afp': {'$all': afp}})
```

The latter query using $all runs much faster with the same indexes - no idea why...

I've tried these indexes (not much variations possible though):

```
{afp: 1}
{active: 1}
{active: 1, afp: 1}
{afp: 1, active: 1}
```

I don't know why, but the latest index gives the best performance - any ideas about the reason would be much appreciated.

Then I decided to add constraints in order to possibly improve speed.
Considering that number of integers in "afp" field can be different, there's no reason to scan documents having less number of integers than in the query. So I created one more field for all documens called "len_afp" which contains that number (afp length indeed).
Now documents look like this:

```
{
    active: BOOLEAN,
    afp: ARRAY_of_integers
    len_afp: INTEGER
}
```

Query is:

```
db.collection.find({
    'active': True,
    'afp': {'$all': afp},
    'len_afp: {'$gte': len_afp}
})
```

Also I've added three new indexes:

```
{afp: 1, len_afp: 1, active: 1}
{afp: 1, active: 1, len_afp: 1}
{len_afp: 1, afp: 1, active: 1}
```

The latest index gives the best performance - again for unknown reason.

So my question is: what the logic is behind fields order in compound indexes, and how this logic has to be considered when creating indexes?

Also it's interesting why $all works faster than $setIsSubset with all the same other conditions?

Can index intersection be used for my case instead of compound indexes?

Still the performance is pretty low - what am I doing wrong?
Can sharding help in my particular case (will it work using aggregation, or $all, or $gte)?

Sorry for huge question and Thank you in advance!

Comment: Of course it works faster. Queries and aggregation calculations are two completely different things. The only correlation ever is the initial `$match` stage, and absolutely nothing else. You are asking for a comparison of "apples" and "oranges".

Comment: Thank you Blakes, but could you please also clarify situation with indexes? Why fields order matters so much and what logic I should apply choosing the right index for my case? Is it a good idea to make a few indexes and let MongoDB choose the best one?

Comment: You've actually made a bit of a hash of the question by confusing different operators and walking over pretty broad topics. That makes the full content here pretty unanswerable in a reasonable format. The index question has been asked over and over again, and is basically very simple. The field selection that will reduce the number of possible results down the most is going to be the most optimal selection. So the index chosen will be where it is at least "potentially" likely to come of with less results in the first ordered field, and then by number of fields that apply.